# C# Validate the first two digits for a four digit console input

Tags: c#, validation

I'm trying to validate input from a console input

The requirement is for the first 2 digits of the console input to be 20

I think

input[0] = '2' will validate that the first digit is a 2

What would the syntax for validating 20 be?

Thanks.

Comment: `input.Length >=2 && input[0] == '2' && input[1] == '0'`

Comment: You need to try yourself first, if you can't do that then do google for simple questions...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any way to combine the two inputs as in maybe input[0,1] == '20' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to accomplish this, but I'd go with `string` method `StartsWith`:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();

if(input.StartsWith("20"))
{

}
```

`StartsWith` will not throw if `input` is less than 2 characters, and `Console.ReadLine` (assuming that's what you are using) will, in all common user scenarios, not return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        if (s.Length >= 2 && s.Substring(0, 2) == "20")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: This would throw an exception if the input were less than two characters long.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(input.StartWith("20") && input.Length >= 2)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Valid Input");
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not Valid");
}
```

Comment: Please add some description as to why this code answers the question posed.